# Meaning of безусловный

Tags: значения

My dictionary(s) define(s) **безусловный** as *unconditional*. Given that meaning, I don't know how to interpret it in this context:

> Я прочла дискуссию о "коль скоро". У меня есть своё мнение. Для меня
>   является безусловным, что только для хорошо образованного человека
>   употребление этого выражения не может являться проблемой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context it means "without a doubt".

Update:
"I read a discussion on "коль скоро". I have my own opinion. For me "there is no doubt" that only for a well-educated person use of this expression can not be a problem."

Comment: Really? That hardly makes sense.

Comment: "I read a discussion on "коль скоро". I have my own opinion. For me "there is no doubt" that only for a well-educated person use of this expression can not be a problem."

Comment: @CocoPop A dictionary also suggests **obvious**. For more translations [see here](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=%E1%E5%E7%F3%F1%EB%EE%E2%ED%FB%E9&l1=1).

Comment: Well Obvious (Очевидно) is right by meaning, but sounds less fancy/sophisticated/educated in Russian.

Comment: Ok, but it still makes no sense. What is she actually saying in simple terms?

Comment: @CocoPop She is sure that only a well educated person can use "коль скоро" properly.

Comment: "Obviously", as CocoPop said works well here, but, in fact, it is the same as "there is no doubt". :) -- good one!

Comment: @CocoPop: You could regard "unconditional" here as meaning "unconditionally true". That makes the usage here reasonable and not strange.

Answer (score 0):

Я прочла дискуссию о "коль скоро". У меня есть своё мнение. Для меня является безусловным (unconditionally accepted fact), что только для хорошо образованного человека употребление этого выражения не может являться проблемой.